# How can I print a QTableWidget by clicking on QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton, qtabwidget

I have an interface with two tab: in the first one i ask the user to enter parameters and in the second one i want to print the following QTableWidget.

So basically on the first tab i have a QPushButton that i called process and normally, when i push on it , i want to send the information to the second Tab.

Right now i just tried to show a new window with the QTableWidget and the good parameters :

```
class Parameters(QWidget):
  
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parameters, self).__init__()

        self.matrixsize = QLineEdit()
        bouton = QPushButton("define matrix_size")
        bouton.clicked.connect(self.appui_bouton)
        self.halfmatrix = QCheckBox()
        self.halfmatrix.toggled.connect(self.on_checked)

   
        self.define_matrix_size = QGroupBox('Define Parameters')
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.matrixsize, 0, 0, 1, 1, )
        layout.addWidget(bouton, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('select half size mode'
                                ), 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.halfmatrix, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.define_matrix_size.setLayout(layout)

        process = QPushButton('process')
        process.clicked.connect(self.process)

        self.matrix = QTableWidget()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.define_matrix_size)
  
        self.layout.addWidget(matrix)
        self.layout.addWidget(process)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def matrix_size(self):
        if self.matrixsize.text() == "":
            return 0

        else:
            return int(self.matrixsize.text())

       def appui_bouton(self):
        taille = self.matrixsize()
        self.matrix.deleteLater()
        if self.halfmatrix.isChecked():
            self.on_checked()

        else:
            self.matrix = QTableWidget()
            self.matrix.setColumnCount(taille)
            self.matrix.setRowCount(taille)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.matrix)
            self.update()
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

  


    def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
        print(qKeyEvent.key())
        if qKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Return or qKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Enter:
            self.appui_bouton()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)

    def on_checked(self):
        taille = self.matrixsize()
        if taille == 0:
            pass

        else:
            if self.halfmatrix.isChecked():


                size = int(taille / 2)
                self.matrix.deleteLater()
                self.matrix = QTableWidget()
                self.matrix.setColumnCount(size)
                self.matrix.setRowCount(size)
                self.layout.addWidget(self.matrix, 3, 0, 20, 4)
                self.update()

                self.setLayout(self.layout)

            else:
                self.appui_bouton()

    def process (self):
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        test = self.matrix
        test.setLayout(layout)
        test.show()
```

So in order to clarify what i said: i have a Window on which you get some parameters (size,...) , when you select those parameters, let's say you take matrixsize==5, then a 5x5 table is added to the window. This table can be after this fill by others parameters (i cut them on the code) by a system of drag and drop.
So now that i got a built table, i want to be able to open a new window with just the table by clicking on the ''process'' button.
So i don't want a dynamical table, i just want a table that keeps the same property (for instance if the matrix has dragonly enable then the new matrix should have the same) . I want to keep every information containing in the cells

I hope i am enoughly clear that is my first time asking questions (after many times reading some answers of course^^)
thanks for your answer and advice !

Comment: Do you mean that in the `process` the table should create rows and columns based on the matrix size?

Comment: No i mean: in the first tab i can create a table with the number of rows you want (i assert it is a square) . And i can fill it with what ever i want. What i want is that when i click on  ''process'' a new window appears with the same table . (that is the first step i want to cross, after, i would like that clicking on process create a new window with the same table with an evolution based on a function for data). I am hope i am clearer

Comment: the first answer send by mistake, i correct it, it is clearer now?

Comment: Well, that partially depends on what you're going to do with the "new" table: should it be editable? should the edited data be dynamically synchronized with the original table? Also, your example is not reproducible, it's missing two functions you're connecting to (`appui_bouton` and `on_checked`) and there's no trace about how the table size is actually applied. Please edit the question and make its code reproducible, including all required functions to set the table size.

Comment: normally like this, it answers the problem you raise @musicamante

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new QTableWidget with no parent (which makes it a top level window), and then show it:

```py
class Parameters(QWidget):
    # ...
    def process(self):
        rows = self.matrix.rowCount()
        columns = self.matrix.columnCount()
        self.newTable = QTableWidget(rows, columns)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                source = self.matrix.item(row, column)
                if source:
                    self.newTable.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(source))
        self.newTable.show()
```

Note that I created the new table as an instance attribute. This allows to avoid the garbage collection in case it was a local variable (resulting in the widget showing and disappearing right after), but has the unfortunate effect that if you click on the process button again and a window already exists, it gets deleted and "overwritten" with a new window. If you want to have more process windows at the same time, you could add them to a list:

```py
class Parameters(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parameters, self).__init__()
        # ...
        self.processTables = []

    def process(self):
        rows = self.matrix.rowCount()
        columns = self.matrix.columnCount()
        # note that now "newTable" is *local*
        newTable = QTableWidget(rows, columns)
        self.processTables.append(newTable)
        # ...
```

Some suggestions about your code:

- there's absolutely no need to create a new table each time you want to change its size; just use `setRowCount` and `setColumnCount` on the existing one, and if you don't want to keep previous values, use [`clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#clear);
- don't use two functions that do almost the same things (`appui_bouton` and `on_checked`) and call each other, just use one function that checks for both aspects;
- don't call `update()` unnecessarily: when you change the properties of a widget (or add a new widget to a layout) `update` is called already; while it's not an actual issue (Qt automatically manages *when* updates actually happen, avoiding repainting if not necessary), calling it just adds unnecessary noise to your code;
- be more careful when adding widgets to a grid layout (I'm referring to the code on `on_checked`): don't use the rowSpan and columnSpan if not required; also, using a value that high is completely useless, as there are no other widgets in that row, and there's actually only one column in that layout; also, don't call `setLayout()` again;
- if you need a numerical value, then use a [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html), not a QLineEdit.

The function to update the existing table can be rewritten more easily, and you should connect both the button *and* the checkbox to it:

```py
class Parameters(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parameters, self).__init__()
        self.matrixsize = QSpinBox()
        bouton = QPushButton("define matrix_size")
        bouton.clicked.connect(self.appui_bouton)
        self.halfmatrix = QCheckBox()
        self.halfmatrix.toggled.connect(self.appui_bouton)
        # ...

    def appui_bouton(self):
        taille = self.matrixsize.value()
        if self.halfmatrix.isChecked():
            taille //= 2
        if not taille:
            return
        self.matrix.setColumnCount(taille)
        self.matrix.setRowCount(taille)
```

Comment: thank you very much for you long comment, i will try this today and see how it works on my code